# Using pointers and structs

Tags: c

Hello i'm not sure if I'm understand the following piece of code. I would glad if someone could read my explanations and correct me if I'm wrong. 

 So first of all I'm declaring a struct with three arrays of char and an integer.

```
struct Employee 
{
    char last[16];
    char first[11];
    char title[16];
    int salary; 
};
```

After that I declare a function which takes three pointers to char and an integer value. This function uses malloc() and sizeof() to create a struct on the heap. Now this creations of the object on the heap is not really clear to me. When I use `struct Employee* p = malloc(sizeof(struct Employee))`, what happens there **exactly**?
 What happens when I use the function `struct Employee* createEmployee (char* last, char* first, char* title, int salary)` several times with different input. I know that I will get back a pointer p but isn't that the same pointer to the same struct on the heap. So do I rewrite the information on the heap, when I use the function several times? Or does it always create a new object in a different memory space?

```
struct Employee* createEmployee(char*, char*, char*, int);

struct Employee* createEmployee(char* last, char* first, char* title, int salary)  
{
    struct Employee* p = malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
    if (p != NULL) 
    {
        strcpy(p->last, last);
        strcpy(p->first, first);
        strcpy(p->title, title);
        p->salary = salary;
    }
    return p; 
}
```

I would be glad if someone could explain it to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such so the homework elves can find it easily.

Comment: No that's not homework. I'm trying to learn C on my own.

Comment: I think it's better to use an enum for an employee's title rather than a string. With bitshifting this also allows for multiple titles. However, this is just an idea, you'll come across this later in your C learning course. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `malloc` function allocates some new bytes on the heap and returns the pointer.

So the `createEmployee` function allocates new memory every time it's called, then fills it with some data *(in an unsafe way - consider using `strncpy` instead)* and returns the pointer to that memory. It will return a different pointer every time it's called.

Each instance you create with this function will exist as long as you don't call `free` on its pointer.

Comment: Thank's that makes it much clearer to me. I have one more question please about the prefix"struct Employee*". It seems to mean that the value given back by the function is a pointer to a struct with the "form" of the original struct Employee. Is that correct?

Comment: There is no "original" struct Employee. The code from "struct Employee {" to "};" does not create a value; it **defines a type**. Its purpose is to say "this is what a 'Employee' struct is". Then `createEmployee()` allocates enough space to store an Employee struct, puts the relevant data into that space, and returns a pointer to the newly created Employee.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is a question about malloc. You might get better results searching for "How does malloc work?" The answer is different for different operating systems and C libraries.

The createEmployee function creates an all-new struct Employee every time it is called.

I also see that createEmployee is written in a very dangerous way. No checking is done to ensure that the strings fit into their destinations before calling strcpy. This is how buffer overflows are created.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` assigns you a block of memory equal to its first argument, in this case the size of the Employee.

Every time you call `createEmployee`, you call `malloc` a separate time, and every time you call `malloc`, it gives you a fresh piece of memory.

This is what allows you to have different employees: if they all used the same memory, you would only be able to create one.

This is why calling `free`, and freeing that memory is important: the operating system has no other way of knowing whether you're using the memory or not.

If you want to edit an existing `employee`, maintain a pointer reference to it, and add a `strcpy(p->title, newTitle);` to change its title to newTitle.

Also, something that has been mentioned, `strcpy` is dangerous, as it will continue to write its strings regardless of whether it has exceeded the 11 characters allotted for it.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `malloc()`, you're telling it to give you a new chunk of memory, at least as long as you've asked for, not currently in use anywhere else. So the following gives you three different pointers:

```
void *p1 = malloc(100);
void *p2 = malloc(100);
void *p3 = malloc(100);
```

It's like hitting a button on a vending machine. Each time, you get a different candy bar that conforms to your requests ("Caramilk" for instance.)